# GUI with xml in java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

Is it possible to create a user interface with java and eclipse using a xml file?

As in android

Thx

Comment: I suppose NetBeans isn't an option since you specifically asked for Eclipse, as Matisse uses xml form file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SwiXml](http://www.swixml.org/) looks like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Google Web Toolkit will support XML layout from version 2.0 onwards.

[Quick Example](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html)

This is a web front end however and not swing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a 2006 article](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/XML/UI-Design-with-Java-and-XML-Toolkits/) about a few options including SwiXml, which produced one of the few decent results in a [2004 GUI building](http://xul.sourceforge.net/counter.html) challenge. There doesn't seem to be many new entries in the field--perhaps people all moved to Web 2.0--except the very promising [Apache Pivot](http://pivot.apache.org/tutorials/hello-wtkx.html) with WTKX.

I think as with any non-trivial project, you have to examine the alternatives based on your very specific requirements. I investigated all those options in early 2007 for a company project, but we ended up [rolling our own](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000007.html) (except using the CSS parser from JAXX) because none completely satisfied our needs.